# Tkinter have stacking frames with list and pages in different modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have code below originally taken from the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter) i have read all documentation in there but i feel im overlooking something, i have pages in separate modules as well as a separate module with a Add class for adding pages to the window.

The idea is to later be able to drop a module in a sub folder with a Pagexxx object within it and call the add page class to allow Tkinter to display it but i cannot seem to get the frames to stack.

Nav.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from Page import PageList
import Mypages

class Windowhandler(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand= True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        PageList("Page1", container, self, Mypages.PageOne)
        PageList("Page2", container, self, Mypages.PageTwo)
        self.show_frame("Page1")

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frameref = PageList.frames[cont]
        print(frameref)
        frameref.tkraise()



app = Windowhandler()
app.mainloop()
```

Page.py

```
class PageList():
frames = {}
def __init__(self, name, parent, cont, ref):
    self.frames[name] = ref(parent=parent, controller=cont)
```

Mypages.py

```
import tkinter as tk

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        this = tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(this, text="Welcome to Page 1")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(this, text="Back to Home",
                    command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Page2"))
        button1.pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        this = tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(this, text="Welcome to Page 2")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(this, text="Back to Home",
                    command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Page1"))
        button1.pack()
```

[image: Example]

Comment: As it stands, your class definition in `Page.py` is wrong: Take the tour [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your input. i believe i have rectified this in my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before asking for help from others, the first step is to validate your assumptions. You're assuming that `tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)` returns something useful, but you never validated that assumption by checking to see if it is what you think it is.

The first problem is illustrated by two lines, which are essentially the same in both pages:

```
this = tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
label = tk.Label(this, text="Welcome to Page 1")
```

I'm guessing you were assuming that `this` would be set to the instance of the `Frame`. However, the `__init__` function returns `None` so `this` is set to `None`. When `None` is passed as the parent of a widget, that widget becomes a child of the root window.

The solution is to not use `this`. Use `self`:

```
tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
label = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome to Page 2")
```

The second problem is that you never add the page to the container with `grid`, `pack`, or `place`, so they will never be visible.

You need to change `Add` to actually add the page to the container:

```
def Add(name, parent, cont, ref):
    PageList.frames[name] = ref(parent=parent, controller=cont)
    PageList.frames[name].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Bryan Oakley that made sense, if you may of guessed i am still relatively new to python but appreciate your tip on verifying my assumption i did as you said and checked, as for forgetting to add it to the container i must of become code blind over the last few hours having checked the code in the link above its clearly there.